# get JComboBox Item Value

Tags: java, swing, label, jcombobox

I've got this JComboBox where the items are the results of a query. What I'm trying to do here is to set a label and a value to each item. The problem is that when I want to get the value of the item selected in order to create a new object, I can't. I can get the label as you can see, using the proveedorCombo.getSelectedItem() method, but I don't need that, I need the ID, how can I get it to create the object "a"? I maneged to get it in the "for bucle" as you can see, I display de label and the value, but I can't take that variable to the create object instance below:

```
public class AgregarPlato extends JDialog {

    private final JPanel contentPanel = new JPanel();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            AgregarPlato dialog = new AgregarPlato();
            dialog.setDefaultCloseOperation(JDialog.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
            dialog.setVisible(true);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    public AgregarPlato() {
        setBounds(100, 100, 546, 459);
        getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        contentPanel.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        contentPanel.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        getContentPane().add(contentPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        contentPanel.setLayout(null);


        Vector model = new Vector();

        final JComboBox proveedorCombo = new JComboBox(model);
        proveedorCombo.putClientProperty("JComboBox.isTableCellEditor",
                Boolean.TRUE);

        proveedorCombo.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 11));
        proveedorCombo.setBounds(91, 56, 168, 20);
        contentPanel.add(proveedorCombo);
        ProveedorDAO dao = new ProveedorDAO();

        List<Proveedor> proveedor = dao.getAll();

        Object[][] elementos = new Object[proveedor.size()][2];

        for (int i = 0; i < proveedor.size(); i++) {
            Proveedor p = proveedor.get(i);
            elementos[i][0] = p.getId();
            elementos[i][1] = p.getNombre();
            int value = Integer.parseInt(elementos[i][0].toString());
            String label = elementos[i][1].toString();
            model.addElement(new Item(value, label + " " + value));         

        }


        JButton aceptarButton = new JButton("Aceptar");
        aceptarButton.setBounds(332, 387, 86, 23);
        contentPanel.add(aceptarButton);
        aceptarButton.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 11));
        aceptarButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                    ArticuloDAO dao = new ArticuloDAO();
                    Articulo a = new Articulo();



                        System.out.println(proveedorCombo.getSelectedItem());


                        a.setProveedor(2);
                        dao.insert(a);

                    }
                }

            });
            aceptarButton.setActionCommand("OK");
            getRootPane().setDefaultButton(aceptarButton);
        }


    class ItemRenderer extends BasicComboBoxRenderer {
        public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList list, Object value,
                int index, boolean isSelected, boolean cellHasFocus) {
            super.getListCellRendererComponent(list, value, index, isSelected,
                    cellHasFocus);

            if (value != null) {
                Item item = (Item) value;
                setText(item.getDescription().toUpperCase());
            }

            if (index == -1) {
                Item item = (Item) value;
                setText("" + item.getId());
            }

            return this;
        }
    }

    class Item {
        private int id;
        private String description;

        public Item(int id, String description) {
            this.id = id;
            this.description = description;
        }

        public int getId() {
            return id;
        }

        public String getDescription() {
            return description;
        }

        public String toString() {
            return description;
        }
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        JComboBox proveedorCombo = (JComboBox) e.getSource();
        Item item = (Item) proveedorCombo.getSelectedItem();
        System.out.println(item.getId() + " : " + item.getDescription());
    }
}
```

Comment: btw: don't do any manual sizing/locating of components, ever. That's the exclusive task of a LayoutManager

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this code to get the ID:

```
Item item = (Item) proveedorCombo.getSelectedItem();
int id = item.getId();
```

By the way, you should use `DefaultListModel` instead of `Vector` to hold the list items. This is because if you modify the vector, the list will not change, but if you modify a `DefaultListModel`, the changes appear in the list immediately.